# How can I model the interior of a house?

Tags: modeling

How can I make a house with an interior? That is all I am asking. Low poly buildings with an interior should be possible in blender.

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

Use the solidify modifier:

Here is my building (cut in half so it is easy to see)

[image]

Then I add the solidify modifier

[image]

And then, my building has an interior!

[image]